# Updating child entity but saving parent entity leads to ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, optimistic-locking

I have an entity like this:

```
class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ChildUpdatedByBatch> childrenUpdatedByBatch;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child child;
....
}
```

I have a batch job, that eventually saves/update a child entity (**ChildUpdatedByBatch**), and a regular action that updates the Child entity.

The thing is that we use **parentRepository**, to update both entities, so the batch job has something like this:

```
// updating parent entity by adding/ or updating a ChildUpdatedByBatch
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

And the regular action also uses:

```
// updating parent entity by adding/ or updating the Child entity
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

But this second one, (the regular action), it is throwing ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException because

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [<package>.ChildEntityUpdatedByBatch#911].
```

I am wondering, if creating repositories per child entities would solve the problem. I mean, having something like:

```
child.save(child) // with child having a reference to out-of-date parent
```

Or, if that would not solve the problem neither.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I use mysql database

Answer (score 1):

Adding repository for the `Child` itself is advisable of course but i doubt it would fix your problem.

You would still have to update the parent with the child so you would still have two `parentRepository.save(parent);` actions if I understand your case correctly. So you would end up with an `OptimisticLockException` at some point anyway.

I would simply apply the general procedure for handling that kind of exception which is:

- Catching the `OptimisticLockException`
- Merging the entity on which save the exception occured
- Retrying the persist / update again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, as I think, issue and, probably, I will be able to clarify a bit the root of the problem.

*MySQL JDBC* driver (and *MySQL* database) uses `REPEATABLE READ` as the default transaction isolation level. It is more restricted than, for example, Oracle default `READ COMMITTED` level.

So what happens in my opinion.

1. Transaction `X` is opened.
2. Hibernate loaded `Parent` with 10 `children` records.
3. Another transaction `Y` started and deleted all `children` records from the same `Parent`.
4. `REPEATABLE READ` means that, if you will load the `Parent` again in transaction `X`, you will see the same 10 `children` records like `Y` did nothing.
5. But! When you will want to delete/update `children` records in the transaction `X` Hibernate will do that, but delete/update returns the number of affected records.

So this is a tricky thing — the number of affected records will be equal to zero, because of transaction `Y` has already deleted all records (this is so called *phantom read*). But Hibernate thinks that he should delete 10 records. After receiving 0 deleted records, Hibernate rises `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`, because of Hibernate considers this situation as abnormal.

I fixed this issue by changing the transaction isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` in the properties of MySQL JDBC driver.

Implementation of `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level in MySQL is very tricky, so you can refer to this article. It has good explanation of the topic

[Understanding MySQL Isolation Levels: Repeatable-Read](https://blog.pythian.com/understanding-mysql-isolation-levels-repeatable-read/)